# Adding Horizontally Scrolling UITableView inside vertically scrolling View

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

I am creating a form based application in which I have a vertical `UIScrollView` containing a different `UITextField` and `UIButtons`, amongst those `UIButtons`, if I click on some specific UIButton, another `view` should get loaded inside the same `scrollView` containing a `tableView` with horizontal scrolling.

I am able to add new view with `UITableView` on button click but horizontal scrolling is not working..

here is my code

```
- (IBAction)btnSelectHalfClicked:(id)sender
  {
      UIActionSheet * formsActionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc]initWithTitle:@"Select your Half" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil                                       destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Form1",@"Form2",@"Form3", nil];

    [formsActionSheet showInView:self.view];
  }

- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
switch (buttonIndex)
{
    case 0:

        NSLog(@"From 1 selected");
        self.txtFieldFirstHalf.text = @"From 1";
        self.superScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(600, 1500);
        self.superScrollInnerView.layer.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 600, 1500);

        self.viewFormOne.layer.borderColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
        self.viewFormOne.layer.borderWidth = 0.5;
        self.viewFormOne.frame = CGRectMake(20, 920, 1700, 530);
        [self.superScrollView addSubview:self.viewFormOne];
        NSLog(@"Content View Height = %f",self.superScrollInnerView.layer.bounds.size.height);
         NSLog(@"Scroll Content size = %f", self.superScrollView.contentSize.height);
        break;

    case 1:

        self.txtFieldFirstHalf.text = @"Form 2";
        break;

    case 2:

        self.txtFieldFirstHalf.text = @"Form 3";
        break;

    default:
        break;
  }
}
```

So can anybody guide me..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: share your code for that

Answer (score 0):

Im having trouble wrapping my head around this.

You want the results of an actionsheet to load a new view inside of the same scroll view that a button was pressed in? Why not just have the button perform the action and bypass the actionsheet, it seems unnecessary and it's complicating your design.

I'm also not entirely sure what you mean by a tableview with horizontal scrolling.. do you mean something like a paginated scroll view? If that's the case, you'll be looking to add UITableViews horizontally across a scroll view.

Programmatically, It's probably better to instantiate the scroll view and then later set it's content size based on the views you're going to place inside:

```
UIView * containerView = [UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,600,1500)];
[self.scrollView addSubView:containerView];
[self.scrollView setContentSize:containerView.frame.size];
```

Reason being, you don't have to plan out your entire content size before hand; you lay out your views, calculate their area and then pass than to the scrollview.

Comment: i have to load multiple form based on selection from user so i am using action sheet, and horizontal scrolling tableview means i have made a from using tableview which is too wide to see in single shot..so i have added it in scrollview with wider width.